# Transferring and storing Photos Libraries via SMB on ZFS

Tags: photos, photos.app, smb, freenas

I have a FreeNAS server, with an SMB share and "Windows" dataset. I am consolidating data, including Apple Photos libraries onto the FreeNAS server. However, as I copy the libraries off of the HFS+ formatted Drobos using rsync, I get all kinds of error messages.

The rsync command I used:

> sudo rsync -vaE --progress /Volumes/SourceName /Volumes/DestinationName

Error type 1 (hundreds, if not thousands of these):

> copyfile(Unfiled/Backup of iPhoto/Consolidated iPhoto
>   Library/Database/Folders/.._390C4171-0F85-427D-972C-B36A8A0BBC4D.apfolder.MxAS1I,Unfiled/Backup
>   of iPhoto/Consolidated iPhoto
>   Library/Database/Folders/390C4171-0F85-427D-972C-B36A8A0BBC4D.apfolder,
>   COPYFILE_UNPACK) failed:45

Error type 2 (hundreds, if not thousands of these):

> rsync: mkstemp "/Volumes/Archive/Drobo Gen 3/Unfiled/Restored
>   iPhoto/Consolidated iPhoto
>   Library/iLifeShared/.._ApertureDatabaseTimestamp.XLAzek" failed: No
>   such file or directory (2)

My research suggests that Photo libraries require an HFS+ file system to work correctly, so it would seem that I would need to create a separate ZFS dataset of share type "Mac" and share via AFP. Is this what I need to do to properly store and serve Photo libraries from my FreeNAS server?

Or, do the error messages above suggest some other problem?

BTW, I have already run a full volume Disk Repair on the source and there are no issues found.

Comment: As long as the [smb implementation on the appliance is 3.3 and supports Time Machine](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/NetworkingInternetWeb/Time_Machine_SMB_Spec/) - you should be fine there. If you aren't sure the rsync implementation on the FreeNAS suports resource files and metadata, you might have better luck using Finder or another app to do the transfer - especially for testing.